# Magento 2.3.1 Not install sample data, need CMS code for LUMA home page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, luma-theme

If we see from the demo here: http://demo-acm-2.bird.eu

There's banners and featured product at Home CMS which i don't get because sample data isn't installed

Is there another way to get the CMS code needed on this one page?

Answer (score 0):

Not easily no.

My best advice would be to install sample data on another dev store and then manually transfer across what you need.